# Make an PAUSE command only one key to continue

Tags: batch

I am experienced at batch scripts but I don't know how to make so that you can press, for example, Enter to continue instead of `Press any key to continue.`

Is there any way to do this?
I have been searching for answers, i found **nothing.** Only the answers on how to make batch file.

Comment: Do you want to change the message or do you want to change the key to push to continue ?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38474438/how-to-make-a-batch-file-recognize-the-enter-key) post.  There are all sorts of ways to accomplish this.. I don't understand why you would only want the [Enter] key to continue?  Also `set /p my_var=press enter to continue` might work.. if you check that there is noting in %my_var%.. your question is not very clear.

Comment: If you want to have different choices for different keys, but those keys are letters, then you can use `choice /c:abc` etc with `if errorlevel ... goto ...` to do that. Choice is the way to go in case you want to build a menu system in batch where the user is not forced to also press enter. If the wrong key is entered, a beep is heard and the script does not continue.